# SimpleInjector can't load type ConditionalHashset

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, simple-injector

The error is very straightforward:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ConditionalHashSet`1' from assembly
'/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AFD44E36-8A75-4400-B431-
CA1B11C6E3D1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/
2F74402A-A942-4912-91D6-A546BE8B4EEF/ECCiOS.app/.monotouch-64/SimpleInjector.dll'.
```

It happens when I try to create a container:

`DIContainer = new Container();`

I've tried versions:

- 3.1.4
- 3.2.0 Alpha

I cannot use version 3.1.5 because of a clash with a new version of Xamarin.Forms.

What could be causing this / how should I try to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The `ConditionalHashSet<T>` is an internal type in the Simple Injector library. The reason it can't be loaded is because it depends on `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>` that should be part of mscorlib, but this type seems to be missing in Xamarin.Forms. This is actually weird, because `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>` should be available, since it is part of the PCL subset of .NET that Xamarin.Forms should support.

Comment: Did you mean missing in Xamarin runtime? Because Xamarin.Forms is just a library. Why would upgrading Xamarin.Forms package make this problem suddenly appear?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey I have no experience with Xamarin what so ever, so I have no idea what I'm talking about. By looking at the Simple Injector code, the only thing I can think of that the ConditionalWeakTable is missing from the runtime that you are running in. I've been looking at refactoring the code so  the CWT is removed, but this is far from trivial.